# How to handle lack of JavaScript Object.bind() method in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, bind, backwards-compatibility

I am writing a bit of JavaScript that uses the `Object.bind` method.

```
funcabc = function(x, y, z){ 
    this.myx = x;
    this.playUB = function(w) {
        if ( this.myx === null ) {
            // do blah blah
            return;
        }

        // do other stuff
    };
    this.play = this.playUB.bind(this);
};
```

Since I develop in WinXP with Firefox and sometimes test in Win7 with IE 9 or 10, I did not notice or pay attention to the fact that IE8 and below do not support `bind`.

This particular script does not use the canvas, so I'm a little hesitant to write off all IE 8 users.

Is there a standard work-around?

I'm getting around sort of okay in JavaScript, but I'm still a bit of a noob. So forgive me if the solution is totally obvious.

Comment: @micha, Yes, missing: `Not supported in the following document modes: Quirks, Internet Explorer 6 standards, Internet Explorer 7 standards, Internet Explorer 8 standards.`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is a good compatability script on this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Just copy and paste it into your script.

**EDIT:** placing the script below for clarity.

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Found a fix for the bind issue and learned to look for the keyword Compatibility in the mozilla docs.

Comment: By the way, turns out that IE 8 has too many missing features. Basically, I need to stick with HTML5 compatible browsers. Without the handy-dandy Audio() there's no point.

Comment: @alex - do you know if IE10 supports bind or does it need the work-around you mentioned?

Comment: @pure_code - I would assume it does (the bind method has become standard so all new browsers should have it). But I have not tested it and don't have access to IE10 right now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14346781/which-browsers-support-bind....I posted a question on it....good answer with a browser compatibility chart

Comment: The article there in the answer is a good short read/skim, if you're sort of fuzzy on the whole `bind` thing.

Comment: A note that copy and pasting the script from the Mozilla page doesn't work out of the box. Lines 13-14 have a multi-line string which isn't properly terminated with a `\ `.

Comment: I usually suggest placing polyfills like this into a script tag which is loaded using a conditional comment. That avoids forcing modern browsers to download code they don't need and IE8 is already the slow-lane so one more file is unlikely to make a difference.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution could be to install [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com).

Modernizr tells you whether the current browser has this feature natively implemented or not
and it provides a script loader so you can pull in polyfills to backfill functionality in old browsers.

Here is the link to generate your modernizr custom version:
http://modernizr.com/download/#-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes

Comment: How to check if the current browser has this feature natively implemented or not using Modernizer?

Comment: This answer is at once totally wrong and somewhat correct! 

It's totally wrong because Modernizr does not offer a test for availability of function binding (probably because the test is as simple as inspecting whether `Function.prototype.bind !== undefined`). However, it's somewhat correct because Modernizr actually includes a function bind polyfill itself! Details of it's inclusion here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/478

Comment: Modernizr > 3 now no longer includes the polyfill for bind

Answer (score 2):

Function.prototype.bind isn’t supported in Internet Explorer 8 and below. Compatibility chart here: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/

Mozilla Developer Network provide this alternative for older browsers that don't implemented .bind() natively:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP = function () {},
        fBound = function () {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis
                                 ? this
                                 : oThis,
                               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Function constructor is the old-fashioned way of doing this:

```js
var foo = function(x,y,z){ return Function("x,y,z","return Math.max.call(this, x, y, z)")(x,y,z) }
 
var bar = function(x,y,z){ return Function("x,y,z","return Math.min.call(this, x, y, z)")(x,y,z) }
 
console.log(foo(1,2,3) );
 
console.log(bar(3,2,1) );
```

**References**

- [Functional JavaScript: Harnessing the power of the Function Object](http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/rg25/3.html)
- [eval() isn’t evil, just misunderstood](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)
- [[Scope] of Functions Created via the Function constructor](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-4-scope-chain/#scope-of-functions-created-via-function-constructor)
- [John Resig - Fast JavaScript Max/Min](http://ejohn.org/blog/fast-javascript-maxmin/)