# Which browsers support bind()?

Tags: javascript

I have to use bind() in the method below.  I only want to support IE10 and up.  Can anyone verify when or if bind() is supported by IE10?

```
    // Verify console exists
    ...    
    if (window.console) {
        logger = window.console.log.bind(window.console);
        // bind needed for Safari but not FF, possible IE issue?
    } else {
        return false; // window.console not available, silent fail
    }
    ...
```

Comment: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Comment: I'm sorry you were blind :(

Comment: Haha yeah I looked there first but couldn't find it. I think that's more for just HTML5/CSS3. The Kangax compatibility table is for Ecmascript5 support. Now you can fully see!

Comment: Did you really need to post all that code just to ask about a single line?

Comment: 'tis gone gentlemen.  Good day then.

Comment: @pure_code Yeah, how dare you?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`bind` has been supported in IE since version `9`. Take a look at this compatibility table, linked from the MDN docs for `bind`: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/