# Unbind scroll event from parent and bind to child element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have html page like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">        
        <div class="child2">            
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I have scroll event binded to parent and in certain case I want to unbind the scroll event from parent and bind to child element. So I tried this:

```
angular.element(".parent").unbind('scroll');
angular.element(".child2").bind('scroll', function(){
// some
});
```

the unbind works but cannot bind it again. Is there a certain way to do that? thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 arguments in angular.bind(), the last one is optional but did you try it with 3 arguments ?? also take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/30530386/4578345