# Why does angular.bind() exists while core javascript has the same functionality?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the angular [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind) it says that you can take an object and bind it to a function with optional arguments like this:

```
angular.bind(self, fn, args);
```

If I understood correctly "self" becomes "this" for the returned (and modified) fn.

This is also easily done with core javascript:

fn.apply(obj, args);

Am I missing something here?

Comment: This way you can mock/unittest better

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529933/what-is-the-use-of-angular-bind-in-angularjs-where-to-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`angular.bind` creates a wrapper function with specified context.
It is a counterpart of `Function.prototype.bind`, not `Function.prototype.apply`.

`angular.bind` is there from old days when it was good manners for JS libraries to be self-sufficient and not rely on standards and polyfills (a tribute to jQuery and `jQuery.proxy`). This often resulted in smaller footprint.

`angular.bind` and `fn.apply` won't work with `new`ed ES6 classes, it is preferable to stick to `fn.bind` if it fits the case.