# Where should I use angular.bind?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I angular we have function called angular.bind. Please tell me where should I use this. As I have gone through this example(http://learnkode.com/Examples/Angular/angular-bind) It is possible to do all the examples without angular.bind. So for What purpose we should use angular.bind? (Please dont block my question)

Comment: `angular.bind()` has nothing to do with data binding.  it is simply an alternative way of calling JavaScript `prototype.bind()`.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529933/what-is-the-use-of-angular-bind-in-angularjs-where-to-use-it) and the response by Davin Tryon. From what he stated angular.bind allows you to attach a function to a scope but execute it at a later time. Personally from the examples from the link you provided it would be much simpler to just attach a function to $scope and access it that way.