# mootools .bind function not working

Tags: javascript, pagination, mootools, lazy-loading

Here is my page:
http://www.b-a.lt/c3150/Seseliai-akims

In this page I using mootools plugin lazypagination

http://mootools.net/forge/p/lazypagination

In FF Chrome and IE9+ all works fine, but in IE7, IE8 bind function in lazy pagination class not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: what does 'not working' mean? do you get an exception/reference error? you are using mootools 1.3.2 and a plugin written by Ryan Florence who is very competent. it stores a reference to `this.bound` after binding it. it seems to work fine and mootools has had a bind polyfill since 1.1 that works across any browser. having said that, I think some minor changes in the bind implementation were done between 1.2.5 and 1.4.5 to make it compatible with the actual spec. either way, your page runs fine for me in IE9 in IE8 document mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bind function is not supported in IE7 and IE8.

The same question has been answered previously
[How to handle lack of JavaScript Object.bind() method in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054511/how-to-handle-javascript-bind-method-missing-in-ie-8)

In my case I was using jQuery so ended using the $.proxy() method, which returns a new function with the context of 'this' in the function set to the object you pass in. Don't know if Mootools has an equivalent function.