# Javascript keydown manipulating object

Tags: javascript, scope, keyboard, event-listener

I'm trying to make an object handling keyboard inputs from the user.

```
var control = new Control ();

function Control () {
    this.w = 0;
    this.a = 0;
    this.s = 0;
    this.d = 0;
    document.addEventListener("keydown", this.KeyDown);
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.KeyUp);
}
Control.prototype.KeyDown = function (event, control) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87:
            this.w = 1;
            break;
        case 65:
            this.a = 1;
            break;
        case 83:
            this.s = 1;
            break;
        case 68:
            this.d = 1;
            break;
    }
    console.log("w: " + this.w + "\na: " + this.a + "\ns: " + this.s + "\nd: " + this.d);
}
Control.prototype.KeyUp = function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 87:
            this.w = 0
            break;
        case 65:
            this.a = 0;
            break;
        case 83:
            this.s = 0;
            break;
        case 68:
            this.d = 0;
            break;
    }
    console.log("w: " + this.w + "\na: " + this.a + "\ns: " + this.s + "\nd: " + this.d);
}
```

The problem is that whenever I write "this" inside the "keyDown", and "keyUp" functions, "this" refers to the document, and not the "control" object. How do I access the "control" object from within the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `this.KeyDown,this.KeyUp` will be `undefined` inside `Control` constructor, you need to move `var control = new Control ();` at the end.
2. You can bind `control` context using below code.

   `document.addEventListener("keydown", this.KeyDown.bind(this));
    document.addEventListener("keyup", this.KeyUp.bind(this));`

Note: bind is not supported in IE8, alternative is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054511/how-to-handle-lack-of-javascript-object-bind-method-in-ie-8)

Answer (score 0):

Move `var control = new Control ();` to the end of your script. Functions in prototype have not been defined yet when you are trying to use them right now.

Then, you can bind the function to the context you want.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", this.KeyDown.bind(this));
document.addEventListener("keyup", this.KeyUp.bind(this));
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg7rLc48/2/).

There are other options as well, but in your case, `bind` would be easier. For more information take a look at the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

Comment: I tried to by using bind but I am seeing an error in console.Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/pg7rLc48/1/

Comment: You have to move this line `var control = new Control()` to the bottom of your code. Also you had one extra `.document` in the fiddle which was causing problems. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pg7rLc48/2/)

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I pasted the wrong url .Here is the correct one
https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/pg7rLc48/3/. I have removed the extra .document.But we will still get this undefined issue if  var control = new Control (); is not moved to the bottom.Thanks

Comment: @user2181397 well, you have to move it to the bottom, because all the functions in `prototype` are going to be defined after that right now.

Comment: @user2181397 Does that answer your question?

Comment: Surely yes ,It is helpful